# How to fix get method with axios error undefined error from 'this.props.match.params.id'

Tags: reactjs, rest, get, axios

I'm developing both frontend and backend of web application. For that I used mongo, express, reactjs and node technologies. I develop API for get,post,put delete and I test it via postmon. It works ! But when I connect it to front end my get method not working. This get method means getting particular object.

This is my api get method ,

```
// get a book by id
book_route.route('/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Book.findById(id, function (err, book){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(book);
        }
    });
});
```

Note this working via postmon, for example this retrieved one object with having its id.

```
http://localhost:4000/book/5cbcc159e4db244de040e854
```

It retrieved following JSON object.

```
{
    "_id": "5cbcc159e4db244de040e854",
    "title": "Miracles from heaven",
    "isbn_no": "439564969",
    "author": "Jense Bend",
    "published_year": 2015,
    "no_of_copies": 34,
    "public_or_rare": "",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to load above JSON object values to my form elements.
So I tried this at frontend as below,

```
  componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/book/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        //axios.get('http://localhost:4000/book/5cbcc159e4db244de040e854')
            .then(response => {
               // console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
                this.setState({
                    title: response.data.title,
                    isbn_no: response.data.isbn_no,
                    author: response.data.author,
                    published_year: response.data.published_year,
                    no_of_copies: response.data.no_of_copies,
                    public_or_rare: response.data.public_or_rare
                 });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

Note,
To check this I comment first line and un-comment `axios.get('http://localhost:4000/book/5cbcc159e4db244de040e854')` this line. It shows form elements with values.

However this line does not worked, `axios.get('http://localhost:4000/book/'+this.props.match.params.id)`

Finally I want to load values to my form. I coded other onchange functions in frontend. 
Note,
Those were rendered correctly when I enabled this line `axios.get('http://localhost:4000/book/5cbcc159e4db244de040e854')`

Is there anything wrong here, please guys help me to figure out this.

Comment: are you sure! get correct id from (this.props.match.params.id)...

Comment: try wrap with templateral literal string

Comment: yes in api inside get method i decleared ` let id = req.params.id;` as this. when I triend this in seperate project. It works

Comment: what do you mean by  wrap with templateral literal string. I mean which part

Comment: axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/book/${this.props.match.params.id}`)

Comment: is api hit when you try with this.props.match.params.id

Comment: in componentDidMount() method inside I console.log(this.props.match.params.id); and it console undefine